# How to resolve error when installing Perl CPAN modules?

Tags: perl, cpan

I have installed the latest version of Perl CPAN on Ubuntu.

When I try to install any CPAN module using the command `perl -MCPAN -e shell;install GD::Graph`, I am seeing the following error:

```
 **root@karthik#perl -MCPAN -e shell**

***Terminal does not support AddHistory.
cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.9800)
Enter 'h' for help.
cpan[1]> install GD::Graph
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.20)
Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz'
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.02)
............................................................................DONE
Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz'
  Database was generated on Fri, 29 Jun 2012 06:14:35 GMT
CPAN: HTTP::Date loaded ok (v5.831)
............................................................................DONE
Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/03modlist.data.gz'
Catching error: "'glob' trapped by operation mask at (eval 28) line 1.\cJ at /usr/share/perl/5.10/CPAN/Index.pm line 524\cJ\cICPAN::Index::rd_modlist('CPAN::Index', '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/03modlist.data.gz') called at /usr/share/perl/5.10/CPAN/Index.pm line 85\cJ\cICPAN::Index::reload('CPAN::Index') called at /usr/share/perl/5.10/CPAN.pm line 976\cJ\cICPAN::exists('CPAN=HASH(0x93dd658)', 'CPAN::Module', 'GD::Graph') called at /usr/share/perl/5.10/CPAN/Shell.pm line 1256\cJ\cICPAN::Shell::expandany('CPAN::Shell', 'GD::Graph') called at /usr/share/perl/5.10/CPAN/Shell.pm line 1681\cJ\cICPAN::Shell::rematein('CPAN::Shell', 'install', 'GD::Graph') called at /usr/share/perl/5.10/CPAN/Shell.pm line 1977\cJ\cICPAN::Shell::__ANON__('CPAN::Shell', 'GD::Graph') called at /usr/share/perl/5.10/CPAN.pm line 376\cJ\cIeval {...} called at /usr/share/perl/5.10/CPAN.pm line 373\cJ\cICPAN::shell() called at -e line 1\cJ" at /usr/share/perl/5.10/CPAN.pm line 392
        CPAN::shell() called at -e line 1
Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz'
............................................................................DONE
Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz'
  Database was generated on Fri, 29 Jun 2012 06:14:35 GMT
............................................................................DONE
Reading '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/03modlist.data.gz'
Terminal does not support GetHistory.
Lockfile removed.
'glob' trapped by operation mask at (eval 30) line 1.
 at /usr/share/perl/5.10/CPAN/Index.pm line 524
        CPAN::Index::rd_modlist('CPAN::Index', '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/03modlist.data.gz') called at /usr/share/perl/5.10/CPAN/Index.pm line 85
        CPAN::Index::reload('CPAN::Index') called at /usr/share/perl/5.10/CPAN.pm line 693
        CPAN::all_objects('CPAN=HASH(0x93dd658)', 'CPAN::Distribution') called at /usr/share/perl/5.10/CPAN/Shell.pm line 1044
        CPAN::Shell::failed('CPAN::Shell', 1, 1) called at /usr/share/perl/5.10/CPAN.pm line 414
        eval {...} called at /usr/share/perl/5.10/CPAN.pm line 414
        CPAN::shell() called at -e line 1***
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Install the `cpanminus` script to get, unpack, build and install modules from CPAN.

- `sudo apt-get install cpanminus`
- `cpan App::cpanminus`

Now install the module GD::Graph with the following command:

- `cpanm GD::Graph`

[How to install CPAN modules](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html)

Comment: Good to hear it worked!